# How to change the color of a div in css when another one is on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want `input1` to change the color to blue, when `in` is on focus. Why does this not work?

```
<div id="input1">input1:</div>
<input id="in">
```

css:

```
body {
    color: red;
}

#in:focus + #input1 {
    color: blue; 
}
```

I also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98f3psLv/)

Comment: Added Javascript tag, as you want solution using JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by changing the html markup as follow.

Your selector `#in:focus + #input1 {` will not work because `+` will select next sibling.

`#in:focus + #input1` will select the `#input1` element that is **next** to `#in` element which is focused.

You can read more about [**adjacent sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/98f3psLv/2/)

```css
body {
  color: red;
}
#in:focus + #input1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="in">
<div id="input1">input1:</div>
```

---

As there is no previous sibling selector in CSS, you've to use Javascript.

Vanilla JS:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('in'),
  div = document.getElementById('input1');

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  div.classList.add('focused');
}, false);

input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  div.classList.remove('focused');
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  color: red;
}
.focused {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="input1">input1:</div>
<input id="in">
```

---

If you're using jQuery

```js
$('#in').on('focus', function() {
  $('#input1').addClass('focused');
}).on('blur', function() {
  $('#input1').removeClass('focused');
});
```

```css
body {
  color: red;
}
.focused {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input1">input1:</div>
<input id="in">
```

Comment: oh ok thanks but how do I do it if I want to select the one before? and not change the order?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner There is not previous sibling selector in CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector, if you want, you can do the same with Javascript

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner yes you'll have to pure JS or any JS library like jQuery for DOM elements manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change color only use CSS but it doesn't work with input element

May be you must use jQuery

```
 .ribbon::after {   content: "Look at this orange box.";   background-color: #FFBA10;   border-color: black;   border-style: dotted; }

.ribbon::after {   content: "Look at this orange box.";   background-color: #FFBA10;   border-color: black;   border-style: dotted; }

.ribbon:hover::after {   content: "Look at this orange box.";   background-color: red;   border-color: black;   border-style: dotted; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98f3psLv/5/